# Changing Title Tags depending on URL parameter

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a bunch of pages, which are paginated using the url parameter `?page=` 
I am using wordpress and would like each page to have a custom made title. So far I've created a custom template an set up the following code:

```
$titletags = array('Title1','Title2');
if ($page==2) {$arrayno = 1}
function ChangeTitle($title) {
   $title = $titletags[$arrayno];
   return $title;}
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'ChangeTitle' );
```

I run this before the call to get the header. Now this code is not working, although it should change the title to Title2, when the url parameter is 2.

The code works if don't use the array inside the function, i.e. I do:

```
function ChangeTitle($title) {
   $title = 'SomeTitle';
   return $title;}
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'ChangeTitle' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not access to `$titletags` array. first use global then get it. try this code:

```
$titletags = array('Title1', 'Title2');

function ChangeTitle( $title ) {
    global $titletags, $page;

    if ( $page == 2 ) {
        return $titletags[1];
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'ChangeTitle' );
```